# Error with simple Spark Rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I'm trying to run this code:

```
val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("phase.handler.test").setMaster("local[2]")
  val context :SparkContext = new SparkContext(sparkConf)

 val ips: RDD[String] = context.textFile(ResourcesUtils.getResourcePath("ips-mock-file.txt"))

ips.collect()
```

and I receive:

```
16/09/08 15:56:01 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/unsafe/types/UTF8String
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDDState$.setInputFileName(SqlNewHadoopRDDState.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/09/08 15:56:01 ERROR executor.Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/esotericsoftware/kryo/KryoSerializable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDDState$.setInputFileName(SqlNewHadoopRDDState.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoSerializable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 27 more
16/09/08 15:56:01 ERROR util.SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-0,5,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/unsafe/types/UTF8String
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDDState$.setInputFileName(SqlNewHadoopRDDState.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
16/09/08 15:56:01 ERROR util.SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-1,5,main]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/esotericsoftware/kryo/KryoSerializable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDDState$.setInputFileName(SqlNewHadoopRDDState.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoSerializable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 27 more
16/09/08 15:56:01 INFO spark.SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
16/09/08 15:56:01 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/unsafe/types/UTF8String
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDDState$.setInputFileName(SqlNewHadoopRDDState.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

16/09/08 15:56:01 ERROR scheduler.TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
16/09/08 15:56:01 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/09/08 15:56:01 WARN scheduler.TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, localhost): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/esotericsoftware/kryo/KryoSerializable
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDDState$.setInputFileName(SqlNewHadoopRDDState.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.esotericsoftware.kryo.KryoSerializable
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 27 more

16/09/08 15:56:01 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Removed TaskSet 0.0, whose tasks have all completed, from pool 
16/09/08 15:56:01 INFO scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl: Cancelling stage 0
16/09/08 15:56:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: ResultStage 0 (collect at EdgescapeHandlerTest.scala:33) failed in 0.074 s
16/09/08 15:56:01 INFO scheduler.DAGScheduler: Job 0 failed: collect at EdgescapeHandlerTest.scala:33, took 0.117149 s

org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 0.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, localhost): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/unsafe/types/UTF8String
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDDState$.setInputFileName(SqlNewHadoopRDDState.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:

    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1843)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1856)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1869)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1940)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:927)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:150)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:316)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:926)
    at com.akamai.csi.application.services.EdgescapeHandlerTest.testEdgescapeHandlerInnerFunctionality(EdgescapeHandlerTest.scala:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/unsafe/types/UTF8String
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.SqlNewHadoopRDDState$.setInputFileName(SqlNewHadoopRDDState.scala:37)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anon$1.<init>(HadoopRDD.scala:218)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:208)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.compute(HadoopRDD.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

here is my ips mock file:

```
1.0.4.0
184.101.107.0
116.6.51.232
80.53.23.112
89.198.8.246
```

I've added import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
yet I don't know why it can't find the relevant class..

I'm new to RDD's

Comment: Have you tried just using Spark shell to read the file given the full path?

Comment: spark shell works, I wan't to run it from intllij

Comment: Could you show your pom.xml or build.sbt?